# How to return to the qualifying rows of original data?

Tags: r, matrix, row, return-value

My code looks like this:

```
set.seed(123)
nsim<-5
p<-2

G <- matrix(runif(p*nsim),nsim,p)

dmax<- matrix(data=NA,nrow=nsim,ncol=p)
dmin<- matrix(data=NA,nrow=nsim,ncol=p)

for(i in 1:nsim) {
  dmax[i]<- max(rdist(G[i,,drop=FALSE],G))
  dmin[i]<- min(rdist(G[i,,drop=FALSE],G[-i,]))
}
```

I filled dmax and dmin with the distance it calculated, but what I really want is to fill them with rows from G. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

See `?which.max`

```
dmax[i,] <- G[which.max(rdist(G[i,,drop=FALSE],G)),]
```

But, consider two simplifications of your code:

1. use `apply` rather than root
2. run `rdist` just for whole `G`

   ```
   dmax <- G[apply(rdist(G,G),1,which.max),]
   dmin <- G[apply(rdist(G,G),1,which.min),]
   ```